# My Code does not iterate over the first column

Tags: vba, excel

The following code does not iterate over the first column.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
   For Line = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


       'Write Read-In Data into target data
        Print #1, Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(Line, 2), .Cells(Line, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value)), "|")


    Next
    End With
```

I do not understand why

Comment: And if I change (.Cells(Line, 2) to (.Cells(Line, 1), I get the message: "incompatible types" and no iteration is done at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Range(.Cells(Line, 2)` <--- change the number 2 and put 1

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But then I get the message: "incompatible types".

Comment: @Marius `Cells(5, Line) = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(Line, 1), .Cells(Line, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value)), "|")`  I tried like this and it worked (the table was 3x18)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over rows. Isn't that: `.Cells(Line, 2)` a typo? I am guessing that it should be `.Cells(Line, 1)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Oskar! Then I get the message "incompatible types" and it does not iterate over anything.

Comment: This does not work for me, please take a look at my code in my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129178/iterate-over-whole-excel-file